# Cannot access Jenkins parameters from a templatized pipeline argument

Tags: templates, jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot access to any Jenkins parameter (ex: `A` as below) from the scope of `myPipelineTemplate`.

From the `Jenkinsfile` file:

```
library 'myPipelineTemplate'

properties([
    parameters([
        booleanParam(name: 'A', defaultValue: false, description: '')
    ])
])

myPipelineTemplate {
    arg1 = A
    arg2 = true
}
```

From the pipeline template:

```
def call(body) {
    def args = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = args
    body()

    echo "$args.arg1" // return (null)
    echo "$args.arg2" // return (true)

    pipeline {
        ...
    }
```

Any lead ?

EDIT: Jenkins ver. 2.107.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST` strategy and the `delegate` is a `Map`. Your `arg2 = true` assigns the property, but the `A` property lookup is a key lookup on that map which is why the assignment is `null`. The `A` property lookup is never done on the `owner` context which would eventually delegate to `params.A`.

With your delegation strategy, the invocation sort of looks like this:

```groovy
delegate.arg1 = delegate.A
delegate.arg2 = true
```

where `delegate` is the `def args = [:]`. The `delegate` in this case handles the property lookup. The value is `null` and then it is assigned to `delegate.arg1`. Your map after the call is `[arg1:null, arg2:true]`. If you change it to `params.A`, it would be like `delegate.params.A` which will fail with a `NullPointerException` because `delegate.params` is `null`.

To make sure the call is resolved to the owner, you could instead use `this.params` (see [this question/answer for meaning of `this` in a `Closure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820084/groovy-meaning-of-this-inside-a-closure)):

```groovy
myPipelineTemplate {
    arg1 = this.params.A
    arg2 = true
}
```

You could also change the resolution strategy:

```groovy
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.OWNER_FIRST
```

```groovy
delegate.arg1 = A
delegate.arg2 = true
```

I would recommend just changing your `call` method from a `Closure` parameter to. any of:

1. `Map`
2. Domain specific object for your pipeline
3. Multiple arguments

For example, for `Map`:

```groovy
def call(Map args) {
  // ...
}
```

```groovy
myPipelineTemplate([
    arg1: params.A
    arg2: true
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        booleanParam(name: 'A', defaultValue: false, description: '')
    ])
])

def params = params  

myPipelineTemplate {
    arg1 = A
    arg2 = true
}
```